# Wait for element to reload using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write a test using the Selenium C# WebDriver and the scenario is the next one.

I have a page where I have a list of users and for finding a particular user I enter a term inside an input box and then click a filter button and select (although it's inside an unordered list) one of the options for filtering. Then the list will refresh and I will be able to click on a magnifiers lens in order to go to its details page.

The code currently is like this:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "customerNameTexbox")]
private IWebElement _customerNameField;

[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "img[alt=\"View\"]")]
private IWebElement _openClientMagnifierImage;


public void NavigateToClientsAppsPage(string customerName)
{
    _customerNameField.Clear();
    _customerNameField.SendKeys(customerName);

    SelectEqualTo();

    _openClientMagnifierImage.Click();

}

private void SelectEqualTo()
{
    var filterButton = Browser.Driver.WaitForElement(By.Id("#filterButton"), 10);
    filterButton.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    var equalToFilter = Browser.Driver.WaitForElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='rfltMenu_detached']//span[contains(.,'EqualTo')]"), 10);
    var js = Browser.Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", equalToFilter);
}
```

I had to use javascript to click the filter because once I clicked the filter button (that is actually the event that creates the filter options) they got hidden almost immediately. 
Another thing is that I'm using a WaitForElement extension method on IWebElement basically it's just an explicit wait.

Now the problem I'm having is that the click on the magnifier is so quick it didn't have time to refresh the list (just the list is refreshed) after clicking the filter option. So it ends up clicking the first entry in the initially displayed list.

Is there a way to wait for just an element in a page to reload when it was existing previously?

Thanks

Comment: Is that an Angular page?

Comment: No, just a normal page. I tried to access jQuery and check if it's active in a explicit wait but it couldn't work so for the moment I'm using a workaround (finding number of total results of the list which is displayed and check until it changes)